# I am trying to make a camera turn on and off with the press of a button, but the GPIO ports are not working, and it is not acknowledging the button

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4

I am using python, and I am getting an error where it says "GPIO.output(24, False)" in the else statement. I don't know what it means, or how I fix it.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Button to GPIO23
camera = PiCamera()

try:
    while True:
        button_state = GPIO.input(23)
        if button_state == False:
            GPIO.output(24, True)
            print('Button Pressed...')
            camera.start_preview()
            sleep(10)
            time.sleep(1)  
        else:
            GPIO.output(24, False)
            camera.stop_preview()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Python gives clear error messages.  This appears to be a Python question,  i.e. not Pi specific, so off-topic.

Comment: reduce your code to only print a message when the button is pressed ... camera and button are not related, they are two completely separate devices

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup GPIO24 as output at the start of your code:

```
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
```

Comment: The error has gone away, but the camera still doesn't preview when I press the button. That might be a problem with some of the other code though. Thanks

Comment: Now it is saying "This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings. GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)" Nothing is plugged into GPIO 24 though. –

Comment: Don't worry about the warning. Does your camera actually work if you just use 'from picamera import PiCamera,from time import sleep, camera = PiCamera(), camera.start_preview(),sleep(10)' ?

Comment: Yes it does when I do something simple like that.

Comment: Amend your question with your new code and add print(button_state) after you set it. Does the output change when you press your button?

Comment: Would I add button_state instead of the "button pressed" string? Also, when I press the button, nothing happens or changes, and the camera does not turn on or off.

Comment: No, just add it after button_state = GPIO.input(23), print(button_state).

Comment: It is printing the letter 1. It is constantly printing them since it is in a while loop though. When I press the button nothing changes.

Comment: So your button does not work. Amend your question with a photo of your wiring and your new code.

Comment: I wont be able to until Friday, so ill get back to you then. Thanks for all your help.